# Push nested Json Values with unknown path into Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

So I don't know why Im struggling with this.  It seems like I should be able to use Lodash or something to do this I would think.

I have an object that looks like.

```
  { "fdjkafdajkfasfjkdaslj": {
      "-LMUD-2APhiSLkEtVbM": {
        "profileName": "bob",
            "profilePic": "www.profilepic.com",
            "score": 73,
            "teamName": "lzs"
        }
    }
  }
```

I will not know the first to keys in the structure.  Example from above. 
 `"fdjkafdajkfasfjkdaslj"` or `"-LMUD-2APhiSLkEtVbM"`.

I really just need to push these key values into an array.

```
       "profileName": "bob",
        "profilePic": "www.profilepic.com",
        "score": 73,
        "teamName": "lzs"
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in javascript (im actually a React.js)?  I was thinking Lodash maybe but haven't found anything yet?  Most of my searches for retrieving nested Key/Value data in Json indicate you would need a path but I will not have the path in this scenario.  I won't know the top 2 keys in this object.  The only thing I have is this predicable object structure with 2 unknown keys before my key/value data.

Comment: Can there be more keys inside an object

Comment: your JSON seems invalid, are the keys nested?

Comment: I was missing a colon on that first key (typo).  Besides that, it is valid Json I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there will be only one key in object as in question sample then you can use `Object.keys()`

```js
const data = [];

const obj = { "fdjkafdajkfasfjkdaslj" {
      "-LMUD-2APhiSLkEtVbM": {
        "profileName": "bob",
            "profilePic": "www.profilepic.com",
            "score": 73,
            "teamName": "lzs"
        }
    }
  };
  
  const outerObj = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
  
  const item = outerObj[Object.keys(outerObj)[0]];
  
  data.push(item);
```

Comment: This did work.  Technically I just needed the `const outerObj = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];`.  That got me the inner key\value {} I needed to push into my array. Also your code snippet fails.  Maybe because the `:` is missing on the first key.  I had a typo in my origin post.  If you fix it I'll accept the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I think my answer is correct according to your question. You got the idea how to get it done, that's matters the most.

Comment: Your answer definitely got me a solution, I really appreciate!!  I was thinking more about others that may come upon this post in the future.  I'll accept the answer but if you add a colon to the `"fdjkafdajkfasfjkdaslj":` value your code will run.  I left it out by accident in my origin post (a typo error on my part).  Your code is fine, it just wont run without that colon i the json object. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use `Object.values`.

```js
const realData = Object.values( Object.values( weirdThing )[0] )[0]

yourArray.push(realData)
```

Comment: This is a better solution if IE support is not required.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON string, it can be found during parsing :

```js
var obj, json = '{"fdjkafdajkfasfjkdaslj":{"-LMUD-2APhiSLkEtVbM":{"profileName":"bob","profilePic":"www.profilepic.com","score":73,"teamName":"lzs"}}}'

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.profileName ? obj = v : v)

console.log( obj )
```